# Intelli j Remote Debugging Unable to open debugger port (localhost:20446): java.io.IOException "handshake failed - connection prematurally closed"

Tags: java, docker, intellij-idea

I am trying to remote debug my application but I getting an error, below are my configurations

[Intellij Remote Debug Configs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlWMH.png)

Comment: Are you sure you have choose the right configuration task? It looks like you have not saved the configuration (IntelliJ is trying to connect to the port 5005 (default), not yours).

Comment: Yes I have selected the correct configuration..apologies I wrote the incorrect port by mistake on the question

Comment: How are you run your app? You have to add -agentlib (On the screenshot "Command lina arguments for remote JVM") and then you can try again.

example cmd:
java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:20446 -jar yourAppJar.jar

Comment: I'm unable to edit the command line arguments on Intelli j. I'm running my application on docker.

Comment: So how are you running app on docker? Can you provide your Dockerfile?

Comment: I'm using the docker-compose command. I unfortunately can't share the Dockerfile/ docker-compse.yml

Comment: So what is your command/entrypoint i the docker-compose for that service?